# Replace overflow content with "..." with html/javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you looks at youtube's main page, you can see that the end of every title is replaced by "..." if it haven't finished. I want to do the same.

for example:
the sentence "I love going out every day" in a short div might changed to "I love going out every d..."  If the user click "ctrl" + "+" it might change to "I love going out eve...".

How do i archive that?

Comment: [Google Search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery+text+more+less)

Comment: e.g. `.title { width: 200px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the CSS `text-overflow` rule.

```
.titles {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

(You'll probably want to set `white-space: nowrap` to achieve the full effect)

[Read more at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: @biziclop Yep, was editing in more detail as you posted that.  Thanks!